# Is it possible to use find command in python in such a way that it does not look for the character inside double quotes?

Tags: python, find, command

I've a file and I want to find the index of some special character (\*) in it. This character might appear at several places in the file. for example:

hello   \*this is a file*/

print  "good\* morning"

I want to use find command to find index of \* only outside double quotes and not inside double quotes. Is there a way to implement this in python?

I know that find returns the index of first character that is found but I've a for loop that checks for this character and prints the index. But I want that whenever it encounters this character /* inside double quotes, it should skip that character and move on to find next one on the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = 'hello \*this is a file*/'
str2 = 'print "good\* morning"'


def find_index(_str):
    is_in_quotes = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(_str):
        if _str[idx] == '"':
            is_in_quotes = 1 - is_in_quotes
        elif not is_in_quotes:
            if _str[idx: idx+2] == '\*':
                return idx
        idx += 1
    return -1

print(find_index(str1))
print(find_index(str2))
```

The function return -1 if it doesn't find it.

Let me know if it meets all your needs.

Comment: I tried this code but it also returns the index of /* when the character is outside double quotes. Basically, I've got a file say abc.txt. So I read the data in this file using open('abc.txt').read() function and assign a variable to it. Say data=open('abc.txt').read(). Now I need to check my condition inside data. I want to check if /* is inside double quotes then return index. If it is ouside double quotes then return -1.

Comment: I tried this string 'hello /*this is a file*/' and it return -1, and I think it's right, what's your string, tell me and I will test it for you.

Comment: # Get three test score
round1 = int(raw_input("Enter score for round // 1: "))

round2 =// int(raw_input("Enter score for round 2: "))

round3 = int(raw_input("Enter score for round 3: "))

#*/Calculate the average
average = (round1 + round2 + round3) / 3

# Print out the test score
print "the average score is:/* ", average */                    This is my file. For second // it should return -1. You may change the character here from /* to //.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I modify it and try it this time. It shoud be always idx+=1 not 2......

Comment: It's still not working. Using the updated function that you provided, it's returning the index for both inside and outside double quotes character. It should return -1 for the line round1 = int(raw_input("Enter score for round // 1: "))   as // is within double quotes. And it should return index number for line   round2 =// int(raw_input("Enter score for round 2: "))  as // is outside double quotes.

Comment: "Enter score for round // 1: " here in your code is just a string without double quote, it just define it's a string.